# What is the relationship between initContext.lookup() and mysqlDB name?

Tags: java, mysql, jersey

I've moved my localhost implementation to another server and trying to use a another mySQL DB.

But i'm getting a null pointer exception when I'm doing

```
 dataSource.getConnection();
```

****Could it be a problem with my jdbc driver?****

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
testProject.resources.ItemsResource.getItemsBrowser(ItemsResource.java:79)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1483)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1414)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Code:

```
// For the browser
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public Item getItemHTML() {

    java.sql.Connection connection;
    java.sql.Statement statement;


    Item item = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    try {

                    connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM ITEMS WHERE itemID = " + id ;


        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
```

Line 78 is  connection = dataSource.getConnection();

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

java:comp/env is Java EE server namespace. jdbc/fyproj is your datasource name defined in context file.

While app server startup, it loads the context files and creates datasource defined with jndi string and database details specified in context files.

When you want to use the datasource, you need to use JNDI string (Which is combination of server JNDI space where your datasource is binded (java:comp/env) and your datasource name defined (jdbc/fyproj)).

Datasource configuration in context file contains all details related to database. So, jdbc/fyproj need not be the database name. Real database your using will be in datasource definition.

Comment: Ok thats not the problem then, could a missing jdbc driver cause the error?

Comment: What is the problem? You didn't discuss anything about in question. Post error stack.

Comment: what is  line 79 in ItemsResource.java

Comment: I would suggest two things, 1) check datasource is not null 2) remove java:comp/env from jndi string and try.

Comment: Not sure. You need to figureout why that is. I would suggest check config.xmls (if you have any).